# MS SQL Server for Linux service goes inactive and stops responding

Tags: sql-server-2017

Ubuntu 18.04
MS SQL Server 2017

After a while sql server process goes inactive

"journalctl -u mssql-server.service -b"
does not show any errors

```
Jan 28 03:01:52 dobrovolskiy.com sqlservr[7723]: [73B blob data]
Jan 28 03:01:52 dobrovolskiy.com sqlservr[7723]: [146B blob data]
Jan 28 03:01:53 dobrovolskiy.com sqlservr[7723]: [73B blob data]
```

"systemctl status mssql-server "
shows

```
root@dobrovolskiy:/opt/mssql-tools/bin# systemctl status mssql-server
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-01-28 04:01:21 +05; 19min ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
  Process: 7723 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7723 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: was it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
systemctl start mssql-server
```

to revive it but I'm not sure why it doesn't revive by itself.